# The best way to config server mixed with wordpress and laravel

Tags: wordpress, laravel, apache, nginx

Hi I have one question to ask for help. I need to setup project that mix between Laravel and Wordpress.

The URL structure is like...

```
www.domain.com/   -> wordpress
www.domain.com/blog   -> wordpress
www.domain.com/blog/{post_id}   -> wordpress
www.domain.com/project -> laravel 
www.domain.com/search -> laravel 
www.domain.com/user/{user_id} -> laravel 
app.domain.com -> laravel
```

for welcome page,  I will use wordpress but in some path such as /project or /user/{user_id}, I will use controller in Laravel.

Please give me any idea how to setup the hosting/server that meet my requirement.

BEST Regards.

Comment: Mixing the two is going to be painful. It might be easier to have Laravel manage the whole thing, but have a separate Wordpress install and pull the content from the Wordpress REST API.